# Adding plugin to meterpreter

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I'm trying to add a meterpreter plugin,

```
a = client.railgun.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()["return"] 
# Math magic to convert the binary to letters 
drives = [] 
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
(0..25).each do |i| 
    test = letters[i,1] 
    rem = a % (2**(i+1)) 
    if rem > 0 
        drives << test 
        a = a - rem 
    end 
end 
print_line("Drives Available = #{drives.inspect}")
```

So I placed the file to `/lib/rex/post/meterpreter/ui/console/command_dispatcher`

Then I restarted msfconsole, but after successfully exploitation, I could not see the `XXX` command (where the filename is XXX.rb) and the `use XXX` command seems to be looking for a dll with that name

So what's the correct way to add a plugin for meterpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct folder to put your script into is `scripts/meterpreter/`.

Once you copied your script there and launched `msfconsole`, you can use the `run scriptname` command to run it.

You can find more details and examples about meterpreter scripting on [Metasploit Unleashed](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Custom_Scripting). A list of some useful API functions when writing such scripts can be found [here](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Useful_API_Calls) and some functions examples [here](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Useful_Functions).